# TableView reactivo in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

Estaba pensando en crear un UiTableView que siguiera el patrón **[MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) (Model-View-ViewModel)** para poder hacer que los datos de la tabla se refrescaran automáticamente al producirse algún cambio en estos, ya sea un nuevo elemento, una actualización o una eliminación sin tener que refrescar toda la tabla.

He estado investigando un poco el tema y he encontrado algunas librerías como **[RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift)** o **[Bond](https://github.com/ReactiveKit/Bond)** , pero no he encontrado nada de información que indicará que esto se pueda hacer directamente de forma sencilla sin la utilización de librerías externas o que esté contemplado en la documentación de Swift.

Agradeceria si alguien me puede echar una mano al respecto o guiarme un poco para conseguir realizarlo, ya que he mirado un poco las librerías y el como utilizarlas pero no es muy intuitivo.

Comment: **RxSwift** y **Bond** son cosas diferentes. Quizas, en su defecto, de algún modo podrías comparar **RxSwift** vs **ReactiveKit**, y **RxCocoa** vs **Bond**. Aunque son para proveer reactividad, **RxCocoa** y **Bond** están mas enfocados a la parte del **Data Binding** y la **UI**.

Comment: **RxSwift** no es mas que una adaptación de Swift del framework **ReactiveX** (http://reactivex.io/). Quizas te convendría familiarizarte primero con los conceptos de propios de ReactiveX antes que RxSwift. Conceptos como: Observables, Signals, Subjects, Subscriptions, Disposable, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias @eMdOS por la aclaración sobre mis errores de conceptos ya que ando un poco perdido en este tema y no sabía muy bien que buscar ni cómo enfocarlo. Con las sugerencias que me has indicado comenzaré a informarme sobre el tema en más profundidad. Si pudieras darme alguna pauta más estaría agradecido ya que se nota que estás informado sobre el tema. De antemano gracias

Comment: Hay varios tutoriales para iniciar. De **RxSwift** podrías revisar https://www.raywenderlich.com/138547/getting-started-with-rxswift-and-rxcocoa . Y de **ReactiveKit** https://medium.com/@diegomarcon/mvvm-and-reactive-kit-2dbbb94f48bc .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualmente no hay una opción incorporada en iOS o Swift (ni Foundation ni UIKit) como tal para los propositos que buscas.

Cómo ya comentaste, personalmente te recomendaría lo siguiente:

1. **RxSwift** + **RxCocoa**
2. **ReactiveKit** + **Bond**

Ambas opciones tienen comunidades MUY buenas en **Slack** y **Gitter** donde siempre hay alguien ayudando.

---

Por otro lado, si aún así quisieras hacerlo por tu cuenta, personalmente veo quizas 2 opciones viables:

1. Usar **KVO** (Key-Value Observing) y **KVC** (Key-Value Coding).
2. Crear tu mismo los Observables (como los frameworks reactivos), que no son mas que una implementacón del patrón de diseño [**Observer**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm).

Personalmente, NO me gustaría usar KVO/KVC con Swift ya que me forzaría a crear clases que heredaran de `NSObject` y perdería la flexibilidad de usar **clases** y **estructuras** propias de Swift.

---

En resumen, implementar KVO/KVC ó el patrón Observer te tomará mucho tiempo. Personalmente te recomiendo tomar ese tiempo para leer sobre **Reactive** y usar las opciones disponibles que hoy en día ya están maduras y estables.

Comment: Muchas gracias @eMdOs por tu respuesta y por los comentarios, ya que me están ayudando a entender la complejidad del problema y lo que es más importante, como atacarlo para resolverlo. Has sido de gran ayuda